# Fiber web framework не могу отправить ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, golang, post, fiber

Я не программист, «а так, кодю для себя».
Проблема — не могу отправить POST (JSON) запрос на сервер.

Что я хочу сделать — сервер на Fiber который со страницы html принимает через POST запрос (JSON, XMLHttpRequest) 2 параметра и после обработки сервер отдаёт одну строку.
Fiber я использую потому что, как-то я небольшой статический сайт для себя делал, а там в «примерах» было всё понятно. Одним словом ctrl+C — ctrl+V, чуть подкорректировал, повозился с html, js, css и всё запустилось! :-)

main.go — старт сервера (тут проблем вроде нет)

```
    package main

import (
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/middleware/logger"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()
    app.Use(logger.New())
    app.Static("/", ".")

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendFile("./main.html")
    })

    app.Post("/search", PostTodo)

    app.Listen(":3003")

}
```

search.go — логика что надо сделать после приёма данных.  (пока просто некий шаблон, есть мелкая проблема, но в основном работает)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber"
)

type Response_JSON struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Surname string `json:"surname"`
}

func PostTodo(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    type request struct {
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Surname string `json:"surname"`
    }

    var body request

    err := c.BodyParser(&body)
    if err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": "Cannot parse JSON",
        })
    }
    fmt.Println("body: ", err)

    todo := Response_JSON{
        Name:    body.Name,
        Surname: body.Surname,
    }

    fmt.Println("todo: ", todo)
    my_request := "<div>" + todo.Name + "</div>"
    my_request = my_request + "<hr><div>" + todo.Surname + "</div>"

    return c.SendString(my_request)
}
```

main.html — стартовая страница

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Proba</h1>        
        </div>        
        <form action="/search" class="search_form" method="POST">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" id="search_name" value="" name="search_name" placeholder="Search name...">
                <input type="text" id="search_surname" value="" name="search_surname" placeholder="Search surname...">
                <input type="submit" id="send" class="search_button" value="Go">
            </div>              
        </form>        
        <div id="result" class="result">
        </div>         
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js — скрипт обработки форм после нажатия (тут основная проблема)

```
let mybutton = document.getElementById("send");

mybutton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let name = document.getElementById("search_name").value;
    let surname = document.getElementById("search_surname").value;
    let s = {};
    s.name = `${name}`;
    s.surname = `${surname}`;
    let search_json = JSON.stringify(s);

    console.log("s: ", s);
    console.log("name: ", name);
    console.log("surname: ", surname);
    console.log("search_json  ", search_json);    

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST','/search');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=request.responseText;
        }

    request.send(search_json); 
});
```

main2.js — пробный js который работает без «клика» (через него пытался понять где проблема)

```
let user = {
    name: "Ivan",
    surname: "Ivanov"
};
console.log("user:", user);


let json = JSON.stringify(user);
console.log("json:", json);
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/search");
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=request.responseText;
        }
request.send(json);
```

И так по порядку:
1 - Запускаем сервер и переходим на main.html. Вводим данные и нажимаем на кнопку и видим результат. Запрос не ушёл и ещё как ни странно строка console.log("s: ", s); (файл main.js) не сработала (вывода в консоли не произошло).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 — однако если использовать скрипт main2.js который без нажатия то вроде всё работает. Данные посланы и сервер их обработал и вернул.
Хотя, почему-то в файле search.go вывод fmt.Println("body: ", err) - «nil», а ведь в переменной «body» находится декодированное тело запроса (application/json) судя по документации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста помогите мне решить проблему. Я google, яндекс, youtube «перелопатил» 2 дня и не могу понять в чём проблема…

Заранее Вам буду благодарен за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ подсказали в английской версии...

```
// Bind the call to the variable 'e'
mybutton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   // Add this line!
   e.preventDefault();
/* ... the rest is the same ... */
```

Самое печальное в том что я вчера вечером подобное решение видел в интернете. Но видимо я очень устал (мои мозги "кипели") и у меня были разные ошибки из-за - "e" когда я решил попробовать эти различные варианты в javascript.